# Как разбить строку на блоки по заданному колличеству символов?

Tags: python, строки

Программа запрашивает номер счёта у пользователя. Он вводит `55437490837429498203`.

Как сделать, чтобы программа разбила строку на 5 блоков по 4 символа с пробелом как разделитель?

Чтобы получилось `5543 7490 8374 2949 8203`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res = " ".join(s[i*4: i*4+4] for i in range(5))

print(res)
# 5543 7490 8374 2949 8203
```

если длина введенной строки может изменяться:

```
res = " ".join(s[i*4: i*4+4] for i in range(len(s) // 4))
```

---

Если пользователь ввел не только номер счета, но и текст:

```
import re

input_str = "Visa 5543 7490 8374 2949 8203"
s = re.sub(r"\D", "", input_str)
res = " ".join(s[i*4: i*4+4] for i in range(len(s) // 4))
```

PS на будущее: не изменяйте суть вопроса если на него уже даны ответы - это инвалидирует ответы.

Comment: Вроде, пользователь уже передумал вводить текст)

Comment: Вроде `0xdb` откатил?

Comment: господа, я оставил основной ответ неизменным - это так, на всякий случай... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Классика:

```
s = "55437490837429498203"
ssplit = ' '.join(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(s)] * 4)))
print(ssplit)
# 5543 7490 8374 2949 8203
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно проще через `enumerate()` сделать подсчет номера символа и к нему прибавлять пробел, если он кратен 4.

```
s = '55437490837429498203'
print(''.join([n if i % 4 else f'{n} ' for i, n in enumerate(s, 1)]).rstrip())
# 5543 7490 8374 2949 8203
```

Для любой по длине строки работает.

Для случая, который сейчас в измененном вопросе, можно пойти двумя путями.

Первый замена через регулярные выражения:

```
import re

s = 'Visa 55437490837429498203'
res = re.sub('(\w+) (\d{20})', lambda x: '{} {}'.format(x.group(1), ''.join([n if i % 4 else f'{n} ' for i, n in enumerate(x.group(2), 1)])).rstrip(), s)
print(res)
# Visa 5543 7490 8374 2949 8203
```

Либо через строковую функцию `str.split()`:

```
res2 = ' '.join([r if not i else ''.join([n if i % 4 else f'{n} ' for i, n in enumerate(r, 1)]).rstrip() for i, r in enumerate(s.split())])
print(res2)
# Visa 5543 7490 8374 2949 8203
```

Comment: Дело вкуса, но можно уйти от тернарного оператора: `n + " " * (not i % 4)`

Answer (score 0):

Использование `range` с указанием шага:

```
text = '55437490837429498203'
print(' '.join(text[i: i+4] for i in range(0, len(text), 4)))
# 5543 7490 8374 2949 8203
```